# Magnetc Stripe Reader Issue in Motorola MC65 device

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, motorola, magnetic-cards

I have an issue with Magnet Stripe Reader in Motorola MC 65 ( OS : Windows Mobile ). If I try to open the Reader, I'm getting an exception of `MSR_Open MSR_Err_OpenFailure`.

Code:

```
Symbol.MagStripe.Device MyDevice = new Symbol.MagStripe.Device(myDiv.DeviceName);
this.MyReader = new Symbol.MagStripe.Reader(MyDevice);
this.MyReader.Actions.Enable();
```

Stack Trace:

```
Symbol.magstripe.magstripe Marshal.open(stringsdevicename, stringsportname) at
Symbol.magstrip.actions.enable() at
Ecollect.ecscancardcf.start read()
```

Comment: Are you sure the device is connected? The message suggests a low-level hardware problem. Confirm first that the sample supplied with the reader is working correctly.

Comment: I assume the MC65 has an MSR keyboard wedge you can enable. If you open notepad and perform a scan, does the MSR data appear in notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying the Symbol/Motorola/Zebra library in your device. I had the same situation, you need install the proper library. 
Is a good idea to have a troubleshoot functionality, to test all the attached devices.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the plug is in properly and blow on it

Comment: Has this actually worked for you, i.e. did you have the same problem and this solution resolved your problem?